# Adhearsion's dialplan can't access rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asterisk

In my adhearsion dialplan, I have the following code that is causing an immediate disconnect from the call without any output to the log or console:

```
the_flow = CallFlow.where(:dnis => dnis).first
```

CallFlow is a model in my rails app (gui/app/models/call_flow.rb), which lives in the gui directory of my adhearsion app. In my .ahnrc file I have:

```
paths:
  # All paths are relative to this file's directory
  init: config/startup.rb
  dialplan: dialplan.rb
  events: events.rb
  models: gui/app/models/*.rb
```

And this is call_flow.rb:

```
class CallFlow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :routable, :polymorphic => true

  def dialplan
    puts self.routable.description.squeeze("\n").strip
  end

  def target_route=(params)
    self.routable = params[:kind].constantize.new(params.reject {|k,v| k == "kind"})
  end
end
```

And finally, I have the following line in config/startup.rb:

```
config.enable_rails :path => 'gui', :env => :development
```

I know the model works because I can create records using the rails server. But I don't even know how to get any information about what's going on to make the dialplan disconnect the call when it gets to that first line above.

Comment: It might help if I knew how to rescue an ActiveRecord problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Ensure you have set logging to `:debug` in `config/startup.rb`
- Ensure you have enabled *either* Rails integration or database integration, not both.
- If you are running a version of Adhearsion prior to 1.1.0, some exceptions that occur in dialplan.rb may be silently lost.  Consider upgrading to 1.1.0 or later (1.2.0 is current stable) and create an exception handler.  This can be a simple message logger or you can report exceptions to Airbrake.  See the bottom of this post for a simple Adhearsion exception logger.
- Try starting the Adhearsion console to see if your models are loaded at all.  Start the Adhearsion console with `ahn start console /path/to/ahn/app`.  You will then have a console similar to the Rails console and should have access to all your ActiveRecord models (assuming the Rails integration loaded correctly).

Example exception logger for Adhearsion 1.1.0 or later.  Put this in your events.rb:

```
events.exception.each do |e|
  ahn_log.error e.message
  ahn_log.debug e.backtrace.join("\n")
end
```

General notes on Rails vs. Database integration for Adhearsion:

- For Rails integration have a line something like `config.enable_rails :path => '/path/to/rails/app', :env => :production`
- For database integration, use something like:
  `config.enable_database :adapter  => 'mysql',
                       :username => 'root',
                       :password => '',
                       :host     => 'localhost'`
- For database integration only (not Rails integration), you should make sure that your models are in a place where Adhearsion can find them.  The default location is `models/` but this can be changed by editing the `.ahnrc` file in the Adhearsion app's base directory.

Comment: Would it be easy to use a newer version of adhearsion?

Comment: It should be very easy to use a newer version of Adhearsion.  Just update your Gemfile (assuming you're using at least Ahn 1.0), bundle install, and go.  I have personally upgraded Adhearsion apps as far back as 0.8.3 without any code changes.  The 1.0 API is guaranteed to be backward compatible until Ahn 2.0.  If it's not, it's a bug.

Comment: You pretty much saved my life with the events.rb part. IMO that should be built into Adhearsion as an option along with a global config file :) Thanks Ben

Comment: This functionality was added to the framework itself in subsequent versions of Adhearsion 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this code in rails console

first start the console

```
bundle exec rails console
```

and then try to run the code which is causing the issue

```
CallFlow.where(:dnis => "something").first # replace "something" with something valid
```